# Is the built-in LambdaMetafactory parameter type checking correct?

Tags: java, lambda, reflection, lambda-metafactory

For example, when I execute the following:

```
public static int addOne(Number base) {
  return base.intValue() + 1;
}

public static interface AddOneLambda {
  public int addOne(Integer base);
}

public static void main(String[] a) throws Throwable {
  Method lambdaMethod = AddOneLambda.class.getMethod("addOne", Integer.class);
  Class<?>[] lambdaParameters = Stream.of(lambdaMethod.getParameters()).map(p -> p.getType()).toArray(Class[]::new);

  Method sourceMethod = Main.class.getMethod("addOne", Number.class);
  Class<?>[] sourceParameters = Stream.of(sourceMethod.getParameters()).map(p -> p.getType()).toArray(Class[]::new);

  MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
  CallSite site = LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(lookup, //
      lambdaMethod.getName(), //
      MethodType.methodType(lambdaMethod.getDeclaringClass()), //
      MethodType.methodType(lambdaMethod.getReturnType(), lambdaParameters), //
      lookup.unreflect(sourceMethod), //
      MethodType.methodType(sourceMethod.getReturnType(), sourceParameters));

  AddOneLambda addOneLambda = (AddOneLambda) site.getTarget().invoke();
  System.out.println("1 + 1 = " + addOneLambda.addOne(1));
}
```

I receive the following exception from metafactory:

> LambdaConversionException: Type mismatch for dynamic parameter 0:
> class java.lang.Number is not a subtype of class java.lang.Integer

I don't understand this. Passing an Integer to the AddOneLambda should always be fine, because the underlying addOne method can accept Integers as part of it's Number signature - so I believe this configuration should be "safe".

On the other hand, when I execute the above with this change:

```
public static int addOne(Integer base) {
  return base.intValue() + 1;
}

public interface AddOneLambda {
  public int addOne(Number base);
}
```

The metafactory allows now this without exception, but it doesn't seem right. I can pass any kind of Number to AddOneLambda, even though the underlying method can only handle Integers - so I believe this configuration to be "unsafe". Indeed, if I now call `addOneLambda.addOne(1.5)` I receive an exception for inability to cast Double to Integer.

Why then is my initial code not allowed, while the change which ultimately allows for invalid types to be passed ok? Is it something to do with the values I'm passing to metafactory, is metafactory incorrectly checking the types, or does this prevent some other kind of situation I haven't considered? If relevant, I'm using JDK 17.0.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have misunderstood the purpose of the `dynamicMethodType` argument of `metafactory` (the sixth one, which you have as `MethodType.methodType(sourceMethod.getReturnType(), sourceParameters)`). The *point* of it is to produce runtime type errors: the generated method will have the type given by `interfaceMethodType` (fourth parameter) but will check that its parameters and return value obey the `dynamicMethodType`. For example, after erasure, `Consumer` contains `void accept(Object)`, and if you do something like `(Consumer<String>)String::intern` the generated `accept(Object)` must do a checked cast to `String`. The underlying call to `metafactory` will pass the method type `void(Object)` as `interfaceMethodType` and `void(String)` as `dynamicMethodType`.

As the purpose of `dynamicMethodType` is to act as "further" restrictions on `interfaceMethodType`, it is considered an error for it to be looser. From a theoretical/user standpoint this seems a bit ugly, but from an implementation standpoint (why generate a useless cast? does producing a wider type indicate a bug in the caller?) you might consider it justified.

To get all language lawyery, you have violated the "linkage invariants" in [`LambdaMetafactory`'s documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.html)

> Assume the linkage arguments are as follows:
>
> - ...
> - `interfaceMethodType` (describing the implemented method type) has `N` parameters, of types (`U1`..`Un`) and return type `Ru`;
> - ...
> - `dynamicMethodType` (allowing restrictions on invocation) has `N` parameters, of types (`T1`..`Tn`) and return type `Rt`.
>
> Then the following linkage invariants must hold:
>
> - `interfaceMethodType` and `dynamicMethodType` have the same arity `N`, and for `i`=`1`..`N`, `Ti` and `Ui` are the same type, or `Ti` and `Ui` are both reference types and `Ti` is a subtype of `Ui`
> - ...

As you are not dealing with generics or anything similarly interesting, you should do as the Javadoc for `metafactory` suggests and pass the same `int(Integer)` type for `interfaceMethodType` and `dynamicMethodType`.

Comment: Your suggestion for change gets this case working, and your explanation makes sense thanks.

Comment: Maybe it’s worth mentioning explicitly that widening and (un)boxing conversions still are possible, they’re specified implicitly by the target methodhandle’s type when it is not identical to `dynamicMethodType`.